# Approximating $\max \big\{\frac{x_\tau}{x}\big\}$ as $x$ and $x_\tau \rightarrow 0^+$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, biology, delay-differential-equations

I have the following delay system:
$$x'(t) = g(t,\tau,x,x_\tau)$$
Given that $g(\cdot)$ is smooth and bounded, $x(t)$ is bounded in a non-negative region. What are some possible ways to obtain an upper bound on $\max\frac{x_\tau}{x}$, where $x_\tau = x(t-\tau)$?

I tried using $x_\tau \leq x + \max(|g|)\tau$, but that did not get me very far. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm mostly interested in the case where $x\rightarrow 0$. I've been trying to involve Lipschitz continuity and some comparison of norms, but I have yet to get anything.

Comment: For any differentiable function, if the derivative is bounded, you can show that the function is Lipschitz continuous (using mean value theorem). From there, I believe you could reach a useful inequality.